# Ruby: Refactoring a method to predicted method

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby. please help, I need to refactor to boolean function return true or false

```
def equilateral()       
  return side1 == side2 && side2 == side3   
end
```

I tried and did not work.

```
def equilateral?
  if side1 == side2 && side2 == side3
end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could write it like this and leave out the return statement.

*Edit Update*

```
def equilateral
  side1 == side2 && side2 == side3
end
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `equilateral` method already returns only `true` or `false`. By the way: the `return` is superfluous.

Answer (score -2):

```
# this will return true or false
def equilateral?     
  side1 == side2 && side2 == side3
end

# with more then 2 values to compare with side2 
# you can try this
def equilateral?     
  [side1, side3, ...].all? { |side| side == side2 }
end
```